# PostSharp aspect not working when implement into assembly and calling that method

Tags: postsharp

I have two three projects

**1. framework
2. Repository
3. MVC Project**

In framework project i implemented  aspect

```
namespace FrameworkHelper.TestAspect
{
    [Serializable]
    [MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method)]
        public class CacheAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
        {
            // This field will be set by CompileTimeInitialize and serialized at build time, 
            // then deserialized at runtime.
        public string methodName;

            // Method executed at build time.
            public override void CompileTimeInitialize(MethodBase method, AspectInfo aspectInfo)
            {
                this.methodName = method.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + method.Name;
            }



            // This method is executed before the execution of target methods of this aspect.
            public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
            {

            }

            // This method is executed upon successful completion of target methods of this aspect.
            public override void OnSuccess(MethodExecutionArgs args)
            {

            }
        }
}


And aspect implemented into repository project 

[TestAspect]
public List<string> TestMethod()
{


}
```

, When we calling method TestMethod() from MVC project , aspect not working , what's wrong on this code.

Its working fine when we use with one assembly.

Comment: Are you running PostSharp on that MVC project? In brevity, PostSharp needs to be enabled both on project that defines the aspect and on project that uses it. Then other possibility is that you have either an Ultimate license or are in trial period, which would make aspect optimizer to be enabled and then OnEntry and OnSuccess adviced may be removed as they are empty (at least in your example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Daniel, Its working fine with latest version of postsharp , right now using 
Postsharp of 3.1.50.9

Before i used 3.1.48 , May be that's problem with old version.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created new project for test the scanario and uploading project into github you can go through and can test home index controller.

https://github.com/virenderkverma/PostSharp-Examples

Project - PostSharpMultipleAssemblyCall

You can test this project